# SQL Server User Login Failures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a very strange problem with an SQL Server login. We can log into the server using the credentials from SSMS without an issue. We can also login using the same credentials from a dev server; however, when we try to login from our test enviornment, we get a login failed message.

- We have confirmed that the password is correct by visual inspection and copy/paste attempts
- I can see all of the login attempts (failed and successful) through profiler
- Login works through SSMS
- Login works from DEV web environment
- Login fails from TEST web environment
- The connection strings in DEV and TEST are identical

The first 2 things I thought of were either the password was just wrong (e.g. user error) or we had a port/protocol issue but it seems like have pretty much ruled those out.

Can anyone think of a reason it would fail like this?

Thanks in advance!

Clay

Comment: Is your sqlserver configured to allow remote connections http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Is there an _explicit_ failure message when it fails to log in?

Comment: So what is different between your dev and test environments?

Comment: Hi All. Rab: yep...it is...and it it weren't, I don't think it would work from the dev site. Adrian: Yes, the failure message is explicit. I didn't write it down but it was clearly a login failure in the trace. Automatic: That is the big question I'm sure. Unfortunately, nothing obvious. We've checked all the big things like IIS service account, the app pool etc and all is good. Even with that, why would the credentials get corrupted from one but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you backup and restore database from one server to the other? I have had similar issues in the past, this article may help:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Missing_Object_Owners

Comment: Hi EJ...good thought but if I had an orphaned user, I woudn't expect that user to work at all regardless of the connection's origination.

Comment: Misunderstood, I thought you had different database servers...so you are connecting to a single DB server from multiple places and 2 of 3 work.

Comment: Hi EJ ... We traced this back to a linked server that had not had it's password updated. Apparently, nobody was using the data but websites were hitting the linked server periodically for no real reason. Solution was to just kill the link.